# Database design for not repeating items in user-feed

Tags: sql, database-design, architecture, nosql

I'm working on a Data-modelling exercise, the objective of the exercise is to create a data model for a news-feed where posts do not repeat themselves.

If user **A** has seen post **X**, then post **X** should never appear in user **A**'s feed again.

Any post should only appear once in the news-feed.

For that I have created following data models for **SQL** and **NoSQL** Databases.

#### NoSQL

**Posts:**

```js
{
    '_id': '56sd78',
    'title': 'this is some post'
}
```

**Users:**

```js
{
    '_id': '6ds7'
    'reads':[
        '56sd78',
        '5sdthj8'

    ] // contains post id 

}
```

Above, I'm storing all the posts `_id` that user has seen into the user collection as an array field called `reads`.

---

#### SQL

**Posts:**

```
| id | title          |
|----|----------------|
| 1  | This is post 1 |
| 2  | This is post 2 |
| 3  | This is post 3 |
```

**Users:**

```
|  id  | username |
|------|----------|
|   1  |  abc     |
|   2  |  pqr     |
|   3  |  xyz     |
```

**Reads:**

```
|  id  | user_id | post_id |
|------|---------|---------|
|   1  |  1      |      2  |
|   2  |  1      |      3  |
|   3  |  2      |      2  |
```

Above, I'm storing all the posts `id` that user has seen into a separate table against the users `id`.

---

Which solutions is ideal for in this case?

Does number of posts have any relevance over database choice?

Is there any better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The suggested approach assumes that the constrain on the problem statement is only to add post which user has read.

If your scale is low, say about 100 qps you can go ahead with RDBMS based solution. 
but if you're expecting it to grow, go with a nosql, with append only approach, preferably a columnar DB, so you write to multiple nodes as well. Something like,

```
[{
        '_id': '6ds7',
        'reads': '56sd78'
    },
    {
        '_id': '6ds7',
        'reads': '56sd7a'
    }
}]
```

Don't update the exiting collection. NoSql data-stores are Log Structured(append only) at storage, and updating is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, You can maintain news-feed post details in NOSQL and user_id to post_id mapping in RDBMS.

But maintaining each and every post_id of a user in a single table will hit a performance issue in the future.

Over a period of time, the number of rows per user in a table increases a lot. You have to fetch all records for that user and need to filter out all read posts of a user while displaying it.

It will be good to use some partitioning to split the data/rows based on the date window.

Let’s assume that you have a certain module which creates one table for each week and all posts of that week will go into that table or you can also have some partition technique to split the data based on the date window.

While displaying posts, you need to fetch data both from NOSQL table and SQL table. Finally, merge the data returned from both tables and then discard the posts which are present in the SQL table. As and when user scroll downs for older posts, you can start fetching data from the older tables.

**Sharding**: You also need to consider sharding of a database user wise to scale millions of users.